# NSInternalInconsistencyException in App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I am new to iOS, using swift. My code is crashing with NSInternalInconsistencyException, but I am not sure why is this happening and how to trace the issue. Here is the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1869111b8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18534855c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18691108c +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x1873c902c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x18cfcdae0 -[UIPageViewController queuingScrollView:didEndManualScroll:toRevealView:direction:animated:didFinish:didComplete:]
5  UIKit                          0x18d09fcbc -[_UIQueuingScrollView _notifyDelegateDidEndManualScroll:toRevealView:direction:animated:didFinish:didComplete:]
6  UIKit                          0x18d09fa14 __78-[_UIQueuingScrollView _enqueueAnimatedScrollInDirection:withView:completion:]_block_invoke.299
7  UIKit                          0x18d09bb38 -[_UITransitionState cleanupWithFinishedState:completedState:]
8  UIKit                          0x18d09e7b8 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _cleanUpCompletionState:didFinish:didComplete:]
9  UIKit                          0x18d09ec58 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _enqueueAnimatedScrollInDirection:withView:completion:]
10 UIKit                          0x18d09ff0c -[_UIQueuingScrollView setView:direction:animated:completion:]
11 UIKit                          0x18cfcac10 -[UIPageViewController _setViewControllers:withScrollInDirection:animated:completion:]
12 UIKit                          0x18cfccb48 -[UIPageViewController _handlePagingInDirection:completion:]
13 UIKit                          0x18cfce714 -[UIPageViewController _pageControlValueChanged:]
14 UIKit                          0x18c7f4d30 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
15 UIKit                          0x18c7f4cb0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
16 UIKit                          0x18c7df128 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
17 UIKit                          0x18cc8c1dc -[UIPageControl endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:]
18 UIKit                          0x18c7f4558 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
19 UIKit                          0x18c7f40c4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
20 UIKit                          0x18c7ef328 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
21 UIKit                          0x18c7bfda0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
22 UIKit                          0x18cfa975c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
23 UIKit                          0x18cfa3130 __handleEventQueue
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1868beb5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1868be4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1868bc0a4 __CFRunLoopRun
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1867ea2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
28 GraphicsServices               0x18829e198 GSEventRunModal
29 UIKit                          0x18c82a7fc -[UIApplication _run]
30 UIKit                          0x18c825534 UIApplicationMain
31 MY FIRST APPLICATION           0x10021a774 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x1857cd5b8 (Missing)
```

Only code that I know in this stack trace is AppDelegate.swift:14 which is the

`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

Comment: on what action are you getting this error?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: @TusharSharma Not sure on what action is this happening, crashlytics is showing this crash happening in my app.

Comment: @toddg what code to share when I dont know where is this happening?